# What are the $~2~$ simultaneous equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Sarath has twenty, two rupee and five rupee coins, which totals $~55~$ rupees.

Let $~x~$ be the number of two rupee coins and $~y~$ be the number of five rupee coins Sarath has.

$1)\quad$ express the given information in $~2~$ equations.

$2)\quad$ how many of each type of coin does he have?

Comment: What is it that you cannot do ?

Comment: I dont understand what the 2 equations are. How to form them in terms of x and y as mentioned.

Comment: Twenty coins: $x+y=20$. Total fifty five: $2x+5y=55$.

Comment: An approach is, you have some known numbers ($20,$ $2,$ $5,$ and $55$) and some unknown numbers ($x$ and $y$). You have some statements. One statement is there are twenty coins. Another is the total value is $55.$ How do your known and unknown numbers fit into those statements? (Hint: a previous comment already says how they fit.)

Comment: I understood that first equation x+y=20, but still didn't understand how the equation 2x+5y=55 is formed ?

Comment: When i solve the equations x+y=20 and 2x+5y=55, i get x=15 and y=5. Does that mean that there are 15 two rupee coins and 5 five rupee coins?

Answer (score 2):

You already understand why $x+y=20$, since the total number of coins Sarath has is $20$.

For the second equation, note that to get the total value of the two-rupee coins, we multiply its denomination ($2$ rupees) by the number of coins ($x$ coins). So the total value of two-rupee coins is $2$ times $x=2x$.

Likewise, the total value of five-rupee coins is $5$ times $y=5y$.

Altogether, she has $2x+5y$ rupees in total, but the question says $55$. Therefore, $2x+5y=55$.

---

To answer part two of your question, we have the simultaneous equations:
\begin{cases} x+y=20.........................(1) \\ 2x+5y=55.....................(2) \end{cases}
Multiply the equation $(1)$ by $2$ to get: $$2x+2y=40........................(3)$$
Subtracting (3) from (2) then yields:
$$3y=15$$
$$y=5$$
And substituting $y=5$ into equation (1) gives $x=15$.

Therefore, Sarath has $15$ two-rupee coins and $5$ five-rupee coins.

Comment: Yes i understood very well.. Thank you soooo much

Answer (score 0):

The total is $55$ Rupees. If all the $5$ coins are turned to $2$ coins, the new total is $2\times20=40$, i.e. a reduction by $15$ Rupees. This reduction corresponds to five coins being depreciated by $5-2=3$ Rupees.

$$15\times2+5\times5.$$